# Java array declares as null

Tags: java

I am having trouble with the code specifically with the arrays. I have a while loop set up for the arrays but it's declaring the arrays as null. Do you know what the bug is in my array section?

I'm not sure what do I need to do to fix the null issues in this case. I have went through the code several times and couldn't figure it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//imports scanner object 
import java.util.Arrays;
//imports scanner object
public class Assignment8_jkaur1240026 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int club_seat = 0;
    //creates and initializes club_seat variable
    int coach_seat = 5;
    //creates and initializies coach_seat variable
    int counting_line1 = 0;
    //creates and initializes counting1 variable
    int counting_line2 = 0;
    //creates and initializes counting2 variable
    int counting_line3 = 0;
    //creates and initializes counting3 variable
    boolean reservation = true; 
    //boolean used to keep the loop going
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
    // create a Scanner object 
    do{
        System.out.print( "Please specify service class  " );
        System.out.println( "(1 = club 2 = coach): ");
        //prompt the user to say club or coach seating 
        int seating_class = input.nextInt();
        //stores the input in seating_class variable 
        System.out.println();
        //line break
        if(seating_class == 1){
            //if seating_class var is 1
            if(club_seat < 5){
                //if club seat is less than 5
                club_seat = club(club_seat);
                System.out.println("Club Class: Seat # "+ club_seat);
                //call the club method and prints it
            }
            else{
                //if club seats are greater than 5
                System.out.println("Sorry we are out of club seats");
            }
        }
        else if(seating_class == 2){
            //if seating_class var is 1
            if(coach_seat < 20){
                //if club seat is less than or equal to 20
                coach_seat = coach(coach_seat);
                System.out.print("Coach Class: Seat # "+ coach_seat);
                //call the club method and prints it
            }
            else{
                //if coach seats are greater than 20
                System.out.println("Sorry we are out of coach seats");
            }

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Sorry we don't have that service class");
            //Say we don't have that class if seating class is not 1 or 2
        }
        System.out.println();
        //line break 
        System.out.println("Another reservation (1 = yes 2 = no)? ");
        //ask user if they want another reservation 
        int another_reservation = input.nextInt();
        //store the value inside another reservation int
        if(another_reservation == 1){
            //if anther reservation is 1
            reservation = true;
            //keep the boolean reservation as true
        }
        else if(another_reservation == 2){
            //if another reservation is 2
            reservation = false;
            //change the boolean reservation to false
            System.out.println("Have a good day!");
            //say bye bye
        }
        else{
            //if another reservation int is not 1 or 2
            System.out.println("Sorry we don't understand that command");
            //tell the user that they are invalid response
        }
        System.out.println();
        //line break
    }
    while(reservation == true);
    //keep going if reservation is true
    String reservation_array_line1[][] = new String [20][1];
    while(counting_line1 < 20){
        reservation_array_line1[counting_line1][0] = "Seat";
        counting_line1 = counting_line1 + 1;
        System.out.println(reservation_array_line1[counting_line1][0]);
    }
    int reservation_array_line2[][] = new int [20][1];
    while(counting_line2 < 20){
        reservation_array_line2[counting_line2][0] = counting_line2;
        counting_line2 = counting_line2 + 1;
        System.out.println(reservation_array_line2[counting_line2][0]);
    }
    String reservation_array_line3[][] = new String [20][1];
    while(counting_line3 < 20){
        reservation_array_line3[counting_line3][0] = "E";
        counting_line3 = counting_line3 + 1;
        System.out.println(reservation_array_line3[counting_line3][0]);
    }
    
    
}
public static int club( int club_seat ){
    //method to assign user club seats
    club_seat = club_seat + 1;
    //increase club_seat by one
    return(club_seat);
    //return that value
}
public static int coach( int coach_seat ){
    //method to assign user coach seats 
    coach_seat = coach_seat + 1;
    //increase coach_seat by one
    return(coach_seat);
    //return that value
}

}**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In each loop you increment the index prior to accessing the current element.  For example, when `counting_line1` is 0 in the first loop, you probably intend to set `reservation_array_line1[0][0]` to `"Seat"`, print out this value, and then increment `counting_line1`.

However, because you increment before you access, you actually print out `reservation_array_line1[1][0]`, which hasn't been set to anything except its default value, `null`, because that's what the *next* iteration of your loop is supposed to take care of.  In fact, you will notice an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on the last iteration of your loop when a non-existent element, `reservation_array_line1[20][0]`, attempts to be accessed.

To fix it, simply swap the order in which you increment and access:

```java
    String reservation_array_line1[][] = new String [20][1];
    while(counting_line1 < 20){
        reservation_array_line1[counting_line1][0] = "Seat";
        System.out.println(reservation_array_line1[counting_line1][0]);
        counting_line1 = counting_line1 + 1;
    }
    int reservation_array_line2[][] = new int [20][1];
    while(counting_line2 < 20){
        reservation_array_line2[counting_line2][0] = counting_line2;
        System.out.println(reservation_array_line2[counting_line2][0]);
        counting_line2 = counting_line2 + 1;
    }
    String reservation_array_line3[][] = new String [20][1];
    while(counting_line3 < 20){
        reservation_array_line3[counting_line3][0] = "E";
        System.out.println(reservation_array_line3[counting_line3][0]);
        counting_line3 = counting_line3 + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thank yo very much for your help, it makes perfect sense now. You are the best!!!

Comment: I need help with one more thing. I am having trouble with printing the arrays vertically. The only way I could think of doing it is by one complete array but you can not have string and int values in one array.

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you mean from that comment, but perhaps you are trying to combine `reservation_array_line1`, `reservation_array_line2`, and `reservation_array_line3` into a single 2-dimensional array.  As you say, an array can only have 1 static type.  One option would be to make this type a String, and simply cast every single int to a String.  However, you would definitely get more luck if you posted a new question in which you attempt a solution and explain where exactly the unexpected behavior is @DennisCallagher